# The SMTP host was not specified. InvalidOperationException

Tags: asp.net, smtp, email-validation, invalidoperationexception

I want to write Email validation for my users. But I have some problem.

I have this:

```
public static void SendMail(User user)
    {
        string verifyNewUser = "http://localhost:9928/Account/Activate/" +
                                  user.Name + "/" + user.EmailKey;
        var sr = new StreamReader("ActivateNewUser.txt");
        MailMessage mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mailMessage.To.Add(user.Email);
        mailMessage.Subject = "Registration on Harb";
        mailMessage.Body = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        mailMessage.Body = mailMessage.Body
                           .Replace("@AccountName", user.Name);
        mailMessage.Body = mailMessage.Body
                           .Replace("@VerificationUrl", verifyNewUser);
        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
    }
```

In Web.config i write:

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="myEmail@gmail.com">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="myEmail@gmail.com"
      password="myPassword" defaultCredentials="false" enableSsl="true"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

But I have a `InvalidOperationException`. 
Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: where are you adding SMTPClient server?

Comment: I use gmail server. That's why I write mailSettings in Web.config. 
If I understand you correctly.